# input tel подсвечивается красным в Mozilla до отправки данных

Tags: html, css, firefox, кроссбраузерность

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с такой интересной проблемой.

Есть форма на сайте, которая видна сразу и форма которая в всплывающем окне.

К обоим `input` подключена маска с помощью плагина `inputmask`

```
$('input[type="tel"]').inputmask("+7(999)999-99-99");
```

Форма во всплывающем окне. input tel в нормальном состоянии.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот форма, которая видна сразу. Сразу подсвечена красным. Если заполнить, то перестанет подсвечиваться красным.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код идентичный один и тот же. Я использую миксины pug поэтому знаю точно, что структура 1 в 1.

Я делал так, чтобы всплывающее окно было видно сразу, предполагал, что как-то срабатывает проверка на формах, которые НЕ `display: none`, но в всплывающем окне `input tel` не подсвечивался, все хорошо.

Я добавлял в различные части документа `input tel` (оборачивая в `form` и добавляя `button`) где бы не находилась такая тестовая форма, всегда `input tel` подсвечен красным.

Проверял на `explorer`,`edge`,`opera`,`google chrome`,`yandex browser` - такой баг только на Mozilla.

Как его устранить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, дело в том, что ваше поле помечено как обязательное к заполнению, поэтому не проходит html валидацию, т.к изначально пустое.

```css
input:invalid,
input:required{
  box-shadow:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="tel" required placeholder="телефон">
```

Comment: А почему оно должно проходить валидацию с самого начала? И почему на одних формах происходит проверка на валидацию, а на других нет?

Comment: Просто может есть способ как-то сделать так, чтобы не происходила проверка вначале, до отправки формы? Очень хотелось бы такой способ найти

Comment: Можно использовать псевдокласс `:placeholder-shown`. Например: `input:not(:placeholder-shown):invalid{border-color:red}` сделает красным цвет границы у не валидных и не пустых(в которых не показан placeholder) полей. Минусы - 1) слабая поддержка браузерами; 2)для полей, у которых placeholder не предусмотрен, придется его задать(хотя бы пробел).